# How can I turn user monitor off and prevent turning on when user activity detected?

Tags: c#, monitor

I want to build a software that when a user press Ctrl+Alt+P the monitor turn off, he can type his password and when the monitor is off, after he finish typing he press Ctrl+Alt+O and got the screen back.

I manage to do it all but the only problem I have is when the user start typing his password the computer detect user activity and turn the screen on automatically.

I use this method to turn screen off

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Form f = new Form();
    bool turnOff;   //set true if you want to turn off, true if on
    SendMessage(f.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, turnOff ? 2 : -1);
}
```

Anyone has an idea how can I prevent the monitor from turning on during user activity?

I don't mind which script language to use, I prefer C#.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: You can expect the user to press one button instead of three.  The one on the monitor.

Comment: Why don't you just turn on password masking for your control?!  You should also make your app turn off the lights in the room so that no one can see the keyboard?...

Comment: LOL nice solution unfortunately it's a system on some machine that I don't have a way to turn off the screen manually and unfortunately the password isn't hidden to people over my shoulder. so I'm tring to find a programming Solutions for this problem.

Comment: If the password is going into your own application, use a masking control (the characters you type are replaced visually with something else, like `*`). If it is something to mask the window of another application, just make a window that is set to always on top, then the user can place that window over the password box of the other application while they type.

Comment: If you don't have access to the code for this app, you could try grabbing a handle to its input control and turning on the password char via SendMessage() and EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR.